# What is the best way to perform a SOAP authentication in a Web Service?

Tags: java, xml, web-services, soap

I am writing, for the first time, a web service in SOAP using Spring Boot, Java 8 and Spring WS Security.
Before  SOAP, I used to write REST services in which I always sent, for performing a login, username and password as plaintext over HTTPS.

But I can't manage to find a good option for writing a login method that complies with SOAP's best practice for consuming the login action.

Here's what I've tried so far: the login action has its own dedicated EndPoint

```
@Endpoint
public class UserLoginEndpoint {

    private final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass());

    public static final String NAMESPACE= "some.fancy.ws";

    @Autowired
    UserService userService;


    @Autowired
    private AuthUtility authUtil;


    @PayloadRoot(namespace = NAMESPACE, localPart = "loginRequest")
    @ResponsePayload
    public LoginResponse executeLoginRequest(@RequestPayload LoginRequest request)  {
        logger.info("Received webservice call for executeLoginRequest");
        LoginResponse response = new LoginResponse();
        String username = request.getUsername();
        String password = request.getPassword();
        List<VnWsCredential> storedCredentials = authUtil.getStoredCredentials(username, password);
        if (storedCredentials.size()>0) {
            response.setAccessToken(authUtil.generateToken(storedCredentials.get(0)));
            response.setStatusCode(200);
            response.setSuccess(true);
            response.setMessage("Login effettuato con successo");
        }else {
            response.setAccessToken("");
            response.setStatusCode(500);
            response.setSuccess(false);
            response.setMessage("Invalid credentials");
        }
        return response;
    }
}
```

And this is the XSD's portion that defines the LoginResponse object

```
<xs:element name="loginResponse">
<xs:complexType>
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="statusCode" type="xs:int"/>
        <xs:element name="success" type="xs:boolean"/>
        <xs:element name="message" type="xs:string" />
        <xs:element name="accessToken" type="xs:string" />
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
```

As you can see, this is very REST-oriented (due to my experience with it).

 I also saw that there's a Security Interceptor made by Apache that should also do the trick, but I can't seem to find out how to make it work

```
@Bean
public Wss4jSecurityInterceptor securityInterceptor(){
    Wss4jSecurityInterceptor securityInterceptor = new Wss4jSecurityInterceptor();
    securityInterceptor.setValidationActions("UsernameToken");
    securityInterceptor.setValidationCallbackHandler(authorizationCallBackHandler());
    return securityInterceptor;
}
```

I also heard the authentication can be made via a "[UsernameToken](https://www.oasis-open.org/committees/download.php/16782/wss-v1.1-spec-os-UsernameTokenProfile.pdf)" but I've seen that it's not a common practice (at least, from what I've seen / heard around) and, last but not least, perform the login everytime I need to ask something to the Web Services.

Which might be the best approach?

Comment: Performing a separate SOAP call for performing a login action of some sort is definitely not "standard" SOAP practice. For authentication and authorization, SOAP comes with a normative framework called WS-Security, that indeed revolves around upon what you cite here : UsernameTokens, WSS interceptors (WSS4J is a standard library for that), ... Now, you may want to ponder how much of SOAP normalization you want because WSSecurity is by no means easy to grasp, whereas you could "just" add an authentication constraint at the HTTP level and call it a day; depending on you degree of freedom.

Comment: @GPI I need to authenticate via SOAP, I don't even have access to HTTP Headers or stuff like that in the project in which I'm working. How could I do a login with WSSecurity as you suggested?

Comment: You mention using the Spring WS stack, so this is the starting point : https://docs.spring.io/spring-ws/site/reference/html/security.html but I'm afraid I've not used Spring WS for 4 years now and can't be of much help (hence the comment and not the answer).

Comment: @GPI I'm having a little hard time in following that guide as in my project I don't use XMLs to instantiate beans (I just go with the @ Bean annotation). So I wouldn't know how to make Wss4j read the children of <wsse:UsernameToken> tag